# How to find a cumulative absent dates from a list of school dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have code to pull the 'attendance' dates from our school days table (eliminating holidays, weekends, workshop days, etc.).

```
AttendanceDate
8/30/2017
8/31/2017
9/1/2017
9/5/2017
9/6/2017
9/7/2017
9/8/2017
9/11/2017
9/12/2017
9/13/2017
9/14/2017
9/15/2017
9/18/2017
9/19/2017
9/20/2017
9/21/2017
9/22/2017
9/25/2017
9/26/2017
9/27/2017
9/28/2017
9/29/2017
10/2/2017
10/3/2017
```

I have code that builds a temp table to give me a list of student ids and the dates they have been absent.

```
studentID | currDate
89        | 9/18/2017
89        | 10/5/2017
89        | 10/16/2017
537       | 9/6/2017
541       | 9/11/2017
541       | 9/27/2017
549       | 9/18/2017
549       | 9/20/2017
549       | 9/28/2017
549       | 9/29/2017
549       | 10/2/2017
549       | 10/3/2017
549       | 10/4/2017
549       | 10/5/2017
549       | 10/10/2017
550       | 10/19/2017
845       | 9/26/2017
845       | 10/2/2017
897       | 10/5/2017
897       | 10/20/2017
990       | 9/22/2017
990       | 9/26/2017
990       | 9/27/2017
990       | 9/28/2017
990       | 10/3/2017
```

What I want to do is for each studentID is compare their absent dates against the school days table attendance dates and find the cumulative absences. I have been racking  my brain to try to see how to do this (temp tables, cursors, etc.) but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm using MySQL 2012 via AquaData Studio. Any ideas? In the end, a report that gives me a list of students with over 5 cumulative absences is what I'm after. Thank you!

Comment: what do you call a `cumulative absences` ?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want five absences:

```
select s.studentId, count(*)
from tempstudents s
group by s.studentId
having count(*) >= 5;
```

However, I suspect that you intend 5 days in a row in `AttendanceDates`.  First, add a column to enumerate the attendance dates:

```
alter table AttendanceDates add id int;

set @id = 0;
update AttendanceDates
    set id = (@id := @id + 1)
    order by AttendanceDate;
```

Then, you want to find five ids in a row.  Here is one method:

```
select studentid, count(*), min(currdate), max(currdate)
from (select ads.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = studentid, @rn + 1, if(@s := studentid, 1, 1))) as rn
      from (select s.*, ad.id
            from AttendanceDates ad join
                 tempstudents s
                 on s.currdate = ad.AttendanceDate
            order by s.studentid, ad.id
           ) ads cross join
           (select @s := 0, @rn := 0) params
     ) ads
group by s.studentid, (id - @rn)
having count(*) >= 5;
```

This uses variables to enumerate the current dates.  It then takes the difference from the `id`, which identifies sequences of absences.  The outer aggregation simply counts these to get 5.

Comment: OMG - I'm so sorry. I have two types of absences to get; (1) cumulative and (2) consecutive.  I used the wrong word here. Cumulative is easy as mentioned above, but it's the consecutive against the dates of attendance that is difficult and where I'm struggling. I will go through the code above and see if it helps me what I need and I very much appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Karen . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with more appropriate sample data and desired results.  Editing this question would invalidate the answers.

Comment: I understand, thank you Gordon. I will do that and do a better job at asking the question. :)

Comment: I selected this response as the answer because you did answer the question that I asked incorrectly. I am posting another question to target the consecutive absences giving more information. Thank you.

Comment: Gordon, if you have a chance and if you see this - can you tell me what the colon does in @rn := if ...... it throws an error when I try to use it.  Thank you

Comment: @Karen . . . In MySQL, `:=` is how you assign variables in a `select`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're after :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5c63f/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT studentID
FROM absent
WHERE currDate IN (
    SELECT AttendanceDate 
    FROM school_days
  )
GROUP BY studentID
HAVING count(*) >= 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5c63f/6/0)**:

```
| studentID |
|-----------|
|       549 |
|       990 |
```

Comment: why you need check back with AttendanceDate? Wouldnt count absent be enough?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if OP provide an AttendanceDate, I expect you can have absence on day that don't require attendance (we can check just for one course, or I don't know). But yes, if we just want students with more than 5 absence, we can remove the `WHERE IN`

Comment: You can't be absence if attendance isn't required . ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I can think of at least 3 ways : you supply absence with a date span (`from` / `to`) that'll put records for each day, whenever you need attendance or not; You work with the full absence table but only want the attendance for a specific course; You have optional course that'll mark you as "absent" even if the course is not mandatory (for legal issues) ;)

Comment: I apologize for using the wrong word here - it's consecutive absences I'm after. It's a state requirement to report students who miss 5 days in a row.