# SQL query to identify students who are absent 5 consecutive school days in a row

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 2012, I need to identify students who are absent from school 5 days or more in a row, using the student information system where attendance is recorded.

I have the ‘Day’ table that holds all the dates that are school days for the year (excludes weekends, holidays, etc.), and I build a temp table to hold the values I want.

I am not getting how to format all this and I hope it's readable!

```
SELECT *
INTO #GetAttDates
FROM
(
SELECT convert(date,Date)AS AttendanceDate 
FROM Day
WHERE calendarID = 2062
AND attendance = 1
)x
```

Output snippet:

```
AttendanceDate
8/30/2017
8/31/2017
9/1/2017
9/5/2017
9/6/2017
9/7/2017
9/8/2017
9/11/2017
9/12/2017
9/13/2017
9/14/2017
9/15/2017
```

I have a view that I can pull the absences for each student from. I build a couple of temp tables from the view – ending with this temp table that gets me to the dates to compare against the school ‘Day’ table.

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempAttendanceThree
FROM
(
select personID
, wholeDayAbsence
, halfDayAbsence
, currDate
, status
, excuse
, description
, case when netMinutes < halfDayAbsence  Then 0
    when (netMinutes >= halfDayAbsence) and (netMinutes < wholeDayAbsence) then .5
  else 1
  end as AbDays
from #TempAttendanceTwo 
where case when netMinutes < halfDayAbsence  Then 0
    when (netMinutes >= halfDayAbsence) and (netMinutes <     wholeDayAbsence) then .5
  else 1
end = 1
group by personID
, wholeDayAbsence
, halfDayAbsence
, currDate
, status
, excuse
, description
, netMinutes
)x
```

Output:

```
personID    wholeDayAbsence halfDayAbsence  currDate    status  excuse  description AbDays
89  265 156 9/18/2017   A   E   Absent Excused  1
89  265 156 10/5/2017   A   E   Absent Excused  1
89  265 156 10/16/2017  A   X   Field Trip  1
537 265 156 9/6/2017    A   E   Dismissed   1
18889   265 156 9/12/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/13/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/14/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/19/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/20/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/22/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/26/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/27/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/28/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 9/29/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/2/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/3/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/4/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/5/2017   A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/10/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/11/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/12/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/13/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/16/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/17/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/18/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/19/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/20/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/23/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
18889   265 156 10/24/2017  A   U   Absent Unexcused    1
```

This brings me to where I’m stuck.

How to read the records for one personID and compare the dates against the ‘Day’ table dates to see if there are 5 or more absences in a row.

Clearly ID #18889 should be identified as meeting that criteria.

I envision the comparisons to work something like this behind the scenes when comparing the absent dates against the ‘Day’ attendance dates:

```
AttendanceDate  89  537 18889
8/30/2017            
8/31/2017            
9/1/2017             
9/5/2017             
9/6/2017        9/6/2017     
9/7/2017             
9/8/2017             
9/11/2017            
9/12/2017           9/12/2017
9/13/2017           9/13/2017
9/14/2017           9/14/2017
9/15/2017            
9/18/2017   9/18/2017        
9/19/2017           9/19/2017
9/20/2017           9/20/2017
9/21/2017           9/22/2017
9/22/2017            
9/25/2017            
9/26/2017           9/26/2017
9/27/2017           9/27/2017
9/28/2017           9/28/2017
9/29/2017           9/29/2017
10/2/2017           10/2/2017
10/3/2017           10/3/2017
10/4/2017           10/4/2017
10/5/2017   10/5/2017       10/5/2017
10/10/2017          10/10/2017
10/11/2017          10/11/2017
10/12/2017          10/12/2017
10/13/2017          10/13/2017
10/16/2017  10/16/2017      10/16/2017
10/17/2017          10/17/2017
10/18/2017          10/18/2017
10/19/2017          10/19/2017
10/20/2017          10/20/2017
10/23/2017          10/23/2017
10/24/2017          10/24/2017
```

I need a query that will count the dates (by personID) and output the results, which would look like this:

```
personID    status  Consecutive Days
89  A   1
537 A   1
18889   A   19
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Doesn't look like MySQL to me. Which RDBMS are you really using? Tag correctly please.

Comment: try https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to format the tables in a readable way.

Comment: Related to previous question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898476/how-to-find-a-cumulative-absent-dates-from-a-list-of-school-dates) You really need to improve your question to make it clear. Gordon already provide a great answer there

Comment: I sure feel like I can't win here. I don't know how I can make my question any clearer. This is MySQL. And yes, I think Gordon gave a good answer but I don't understand it. I didn't want to continue posting on the other question since the recommendation was to repost. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @Karen dont take it personal. Use it as an opportunity to improve because no one is perfect. Next time you can include the link to the related question so other can know what have you already try. Another good link [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But if you want to learn you are going to fast. Try simple things first. Walk before run.

Comment: Thank you Juan - I do appreciate your help. And I know it can be an opportunity to improve. :) And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to have a consecutive ID on your attendance table...

```
ID AttendanceDate
1  8/30/2017
2  8/31/2017
3  9/1/2017
4  9/5/2017
5  9/6/2017
6  9/7/2017
7  9/8/2017
8  9/11/2017
9  9/12/2017
10 9/13/2017
11 9/14/2017
12 9/15/2017
```

Then you can build the 5 days ranges

```
SELECT A1.AttendanceDate as range_start, 
       A2.AttendanceDate as range_end
FROM Attendance A1    
JOIN Attendance A2
  ON A1.ID = A2.ID - 5
```

Now you can check if your student has more than 5 absence in that range

```
 SELECT range_start, range_end, personID
 FROM yourPersonTable
 JOIN ( SELECT A1.AttendanceDate as range_start, 
               A2.AttendanceDate as range_end
        FROM Attendance A1    
        JOIN Attendance A2
          ON A1.ID = A2.ID - 5) as Q
   ON yourPersonTable.currDate BETWEEN range_start AND range_end
 GROUP BY range_start, range_end, personID
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN excuse = 'Unexcused' THEN 1 END) >= 5
```

*Note your schema isnt clear so I'm doing some guessing there*

Comment: Juan, that is certainly getting me closer - thank you. It gives multiple records, but identifies the students which I can then get unique IDs.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes.I can see what you mean. But again I work with a lot of guesses. You need to improve your question writing skills. Provide more information on what you need.

Comment: I wish I understood what you need to make it clearer, because it seems so clear to me. I took the time to put the code I'm using and the result sets and what I think needs to go on behind the scenes and what the ouput should look like.  But anyhow - your code helped me and I appreciate it. Thank you for your feedback as well.

Comment: First the tables are bad formated, try [**THIS**](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) to make it better. Then your desire output isnt clear because isnt attach with any explain about the logic. Also there is some part in your query with halfAbsence,  But that doesnt seem to be relevant for the question. So is better if you remove it to make the question simpler. Check this [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)